# FasterCSV importing Decimals and Integers with commas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using FasterCSV to import some pretty crucial finacial data and have noticed that some integer and decimal values are being imported incorrectly as they come from Excel sheets saved as CSVs and therefore have commas added, for example "1,193" gets imported as 1. For strings, it handles the import as expected.

Is there anything I can do in my FasterCSV script to parse out the commas before import on the integer and decimal columns only? I need the strings left as is.

The first line handling the import is as follows:

```
 FasterCSV.parse(uploaded_io, {:headers => true, :quote_char => '"', :col_sep => ','}).each do |row_data|
```

Is there something I can add along with :quote_char and :col_sep?

I'm importing into MySQL in development and PostgreSQL in production.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Obviously, I can format numbers in Excel prior to saving a CSV but this isn't practical.

Comment: I added gsub to one of the imported columns and it works for values with commas but imports nulls for all other values! 'units_sold' =>  row_data[12].gsub!(',', '') . Can anyone help?